# symfony 4 entity manager flush doesn't work sometimes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm not an expert at symfony and some help would be much appreciated.

I'm using an API to receive live match data(sports). I get the data and update it every minute, but somehow it gets updated every 8 to 15 minutes on live. (I was using predis for cache, removed it, still the same). It's also not updated on the db, I check to see if they're updated with dump, they look fine.

Code I'm using is;

```
        foreach ($response['result'] as $result) {
        $findFixture = $this->em->getRepository('App:Fixtures')->findOneBy(['fixtureId' => $result['fixture_id']]);
        if(is_null($findFixture)){
            $cannotFind[] = $result['fixture_id'];
            continue;
        }else{
            $updateFixture[$findFixture->getFixtureId()]['elapsedFirst'] = $findFixture->getElapsed();
        }

        $eventDate = new DateTime();
        $eventDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));
        $eventDate->setTimestamp($result['event_timestamp']);

        $firstHalfStart = new DateTime();
        $eventDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));
        $firstHalfStart->setTimestamp($result['firstHalfStart']);

        $secondHalfStart = new DateTime();
        $eventDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));
        $secondHalfStart->setTimestamp($result['secondHalfStart']);

        if($findFixture->getElapsed() !== $result['elapsed']){
            $persist = true;
        }else{
            $persist = false;
        }

        $findFixture
            ->setScore($result['score'])
            ->setElapsed($result['elapsed'])
            ->setStatus($result['statusShort'])
            ->setVenue($result['venue'])
            ->setReferee($result['referee'])
            ->setGoalsAwayTeam($result['goalsAwayTeam'])
            ->setGoalsHomeTeam($result['goalsHomeTeam']);

        if($persist) $this->em->persist($findFixture);
        $updateFixture[$findFixture->getFixtureId()]['persist'] = $persist;


        if(isset($result['events']) && is_array($result['events'])){

            foreach ($result['events'] AS $k => $v){
                $result['events'][$k]['fixture_id'] = $findFixture->getFixtureId();
            }

            $this->renderFixtureEvents([$findFixture->getFixtureId() => $result['events'] ],false);
        }

        $this->em->flush();
        $updateFixture[$findFixture->getFixtureId()]['elapsedLast'] = $result['elapsed'];
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Best guess from what I can see here and when you say "it works every 8 to 15 minutes" is to double check the `if ($persist)`. I mean, you said yourself, it works, just every 8 to 15 minutes... this might signal something is wrong with your data.

Comment: I checked the data multiple times, it is updated every minute and working perfectly fine. But in my code even though I'm trying to update it every minute, it gets updated every 8-15 minutes randomly (not every minute). I tried pretty much everthing, can't see what I'm missing out.

Comment: I'm assuming `getElapsed()` contains a DateTime-object? Have you checked if response/fixture have different formats?

Comment: getElapsed() contain a Integer